# ¿Como actualizar dos contextos contexto de base de datos en c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Tengo que crear 3 tablas en el contecto que viene por default en c#, para lo cual el contexto se llama **ApplicationDbContext**, por lo que hice lo siguiente

en el archivo de nombre IdentityModel.cs  hice los siguiente cambios

```
 using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;

namespace WebDBT.Models
{
    // Puede agregar datos del perfil del usuario agregando más propiedades a la clase ApplicationUser. Para más información, visite http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594.
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Tenga en cuenta que el valor de authenticationType debe coincidir con el definido en CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Agregar aquí notificaciones personalizadas de usuario
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        public DbSet<MtoModulo> MtoModulo { get; set; }
        public DbSet<MtoOperacion> MtoOperacion { get; set; }

    }


    public class MtoModulo {
        [key]
        public int MtoModuloId { get; set; }

        public int Descripcion { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<MtoOperacion> MtoOperacion { get; set; }
    }


    public class MtoOperacion {
        public int MtoOperacionId { get; set; }
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }
        public int MtoModuloId { get; set; }

        public virtual MtoModulo MtoModulo { get; set; }
    }

   }
```

hasta aquí no hay problemas, el problema radica en que cuando quiero actualizar el contexto desde la consola con:

1.-Update-Database -ConfigurationTypeName  WebDBT.ApplicationDbContext

me manda el siguiente error

```
The context type 'WebDBT.ApplicationDbContext' was not found in the assembly 'WebDBT'.
```

podrian ayudarme para saber como actualizar el contexto, ya que tengo 2 contextos.

muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar esto código?

```
Update-Database -configuration WebDBT.Migrations.Configuration -Verbose
```

**Actualización:**

Si tienes múltiple context, puedes tratar eso:

```
enable-migrations -ContextTypeName WebDBT.Contexts.YourContextName -MigrationsDirectory:MigrationWebDBTContext
Add-Migration -configuration WebDBT.MigrationWebDBTContext.Configuration YourMigrations_001 –Force
Update-Database -configuration WebDBT.MigrationWebDBTContext.Configuration -Verbose
```

Espero que esto ayude...

Comment: que tal amigo,muchas gracias por responder ya intente pero no me deja me muestra el siguiente error: El tipo 'WebDBT.Models.ApplicationDbContext' no hereda de 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration'. Los tipos de configuración de migraciones deben extenderse de 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration'.

Comment: Hola amigo, de nada. He actualizado la respuesta, podría verla y intentarla otra vez?

Comment: que tal amigo buenas noches que crees que ejecuta; pero me considera los models de los 2 contextos

Comment: Puedes ver la actualización para múltiple contexts?

Comment: que tal amigo no, no he podido por lo que opte por tomar otra alternativa, aun asi sigue vive la pregunta para ver si existe una manera de como actualizar un contexto definido por el usuario